# calling vim's input() function sometimes puts ^L at the prompt for some reason

Tags: vim

I have code that looks like this:

```
let s:append_file = ''
let s:append_file = input("print messages to file: ", s:append_file)
```

This code executes fine, but sometimes the prompt looks like this:

```
print messages to file: ^L
```

Why does the ^L character appear there and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: the best guess I could have is that there is some `redraw` involved somewhere. What happens if you set `lazyredraw`?

Answer (score 1):

That `^L` may come from a mapping or some autocmd using `feedkeys()`. You need to use `inputsave()` before `input()` and `inputrestore()` after `input()` to avoid that.